How to overlay the map with blob object of a TIFF file
As shown in the below posted code, I am trying to instantiate an object from GeoTIFF class and set a blob to the blob object. The blob contains data as shown in the section blob contents below.
When I run the code, and when the execution reaches the code posted in section GeoTIFF instance, the entire screen gets covered in white despite the blob object refers to very small area on the map.
As an attempt to solve this issue, I commented out the following line:
map.setView(source.getView())

but at run time, the white color did not cover the screen but also no GeoTIFF has overlayed the map.
The GeoTIFF is in EPSG:3857
How can I correctly overlay the map with a blob object?
imports:
addTileLayerToMap:
import TileLayerWebGL from 'ol/layer/WebGLTile.js';
addTileLayerToMap(map, source) {
    if (source) {
        const tileLayer = new TileLayerWebGL({
            source: source,
        });

        if (tileLayer) {
            map.addLayer(tileLayer);
            map.setView(source.getView());
        }
    }
}

GeoTIFF instance:
geoTIFFSource = new GeoTIFF({
    wrapX: true,
    sources: [
      {
        blob: res,
        overviews: ['https://openlayers.org/data/raster/no-overviews.tif.ovr'],
      },
    ],
});
this.#mapBuilderInstance.addTileLayerToMap(this.#mapInstance, geoTIFFSource);
                

contents or res:
res is an object of type blob
"blob:http://localhost:8080/0002c2e6-9198-4016-bb42-427268458d94"


That is not a valid blob.  You need to fetch the url http://localhost:8080/0002c2e6-9198-4016-bb42-427268458d94 and convert the response to a blob as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/cog-blob.html  (or you could use the url directly in the GeoTIFF source).

@Mike i modified it in the question . pls have a look

http://localhost:8080/0002c2e6-9198-4016-bb42-427268458d94 is a url, not a blob.  Either fetch it as in the example to create a blob or replace blob: res, with url: res,.
